# Bootstrap Drop down not working. I have tried other solutions but the dropdown does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap drop-down menu is not working.  I have tried other solutions but they seem not to work.
Any clues as to why.

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Below is my script source.

Comment: `Below is my script source.` where is your source?

Comment: This is my source [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) under the navbar section.

Comment: Where is your script source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <head>

    <body>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span> </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AltBrian ok check the updated one, also, do hard reload after you updated the code

Comment: What is hard reload?

Comment: @AltBrian if you have google chrome, open console, then go back to browswer right click refresh then select the hard reload

Comment: @AltBrian Cool =D